# error while downloading softwares

Tags: 15.04

i am using the Ubuntu version 15.04. Some of the software can't be downloaded and it's been displayed that the software package is not in your current software resources.So should i install 14.04 ?or the same problem exists in 14.04 also.
P.s:I was trying to download Netbeans IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `netbeans` package is not in the Vivid repositories yet](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=netbeans&searchon=names); you can install the version present in the Trusty repositories tough:

1. Add the `main` and `universe` Trusty repositories to Vivid: `echo -e 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe\ndeb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Update the `apt` cache: `sudo apt-get update`
3. Install the `netbeans` package version present in the  Trusty repositories: `sudo apt-get -tTrusty install netbeans`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you ticked all the check boxs in the software source manager. especially you might be enable canonical partner software sources.

Comment: no i was downloading netbeans from the ubuntu sooftware centre itself